# Nextjs Error: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: reactjs, datetime, npm, next.js

[image]

Hi i am creating a project using nextjs and reactjs ,i am facing an issue, when I am trying to import datetime from npm date-time package ,its throwing this error.I am using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-time. The error in my code is shown in the picture attached

This is my next.config.js what i need to

```
   const path = require("path");
const withCss = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withImages = require("next-images");
module.exports = withImages(
  withSass(
    withCss({
      webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        if (isServer) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
              loader: "url-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 100000,
                name: "[name].[ext]",
              },
            },
          });
        }
        return config;
      },
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        url: false,
      },
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: This means that `date-time` is shipping ESM in `node_modules` instead of CJS. Since Next's server still only supports CJS, you'll need to use one of these [workarounds](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25423#issuecomment-847422832) (I'd recommend option 2). This transition to ESM is happening all across the dev world, but some frameworks (like NextJS) and packages (like Jest) either can't (due to node limitations) or won't add support until it becomes more universally adopted/supported/stable.

Comment: Looking a bit deeper into the dependencies, it looks like the author is using `"type": "module"` in both of their package.jsons (one for `date-time` and one for `time-zone`), This tells Webpack that **all files** loaded by Webpack are expected to be ES modules. This could have been avoided had they used the `.mjs` extension.

Comment: Matt Carlotta . I have included my next.config.js ,actually i am new in nextjs can you please tell me ,what all the changes i need to do in my next.config.js

Comment: You really don't even need to mess with your Next config, instead just copy this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mattcarlotta/ebfb42a71a545e0ff942bf38d7f15751) to a local file and use it as if it were a utility function: ```import datetime from "./path/to/utils/datetime";```.